# CiviContribute Disappeared

Tags: civicontribute

We were on version 5.12 of Civi with WP 5.1.2 when I noticed our Donate page didn't work.  After digging I noticed the CiviContribute was missing from the Components page.  We upgraded to civi 5.18 and still no CiviContribute:
[image: Missing CiviContribute]

Any way to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What is civisubmit? It looks like contribute has been renamed.

Comment: Perhaps a really well working Word replacement Contribute -> Submit?

Comment: Hmm... good question?  I didn't even notice that...  WOW this is crazy.  In the Word replacement Contribute is replaced with Submit.  I wonder why?  I don't think we did that.

Comment: Also odd because I wouldn't expect word replacements to translate dropdown choices (the checkboxes are basically a multiselect dropdown).

Comment: I turned on CiviSubmit (Contribution) and now it works.  I guess sometime we put the word replacement in not sure how the Component got turned off though.

Comment: I had no idea you could actually do that - cool :-)

Answer (score 2):

User error!    I turned on CiviSubmit (Contribution) and now it works. I guess sometime we put the word replacement in not sure how the Component got turned off though.

I removed the Word Replacement and turned on CiviContribute and tested the donation page ok!